# Can i validate URL for an image on my computer

Tags: asp.net, validation, url, webforms

Im new to web programming.
I have made this app for cosmetics online store, just an assignment for my school.
I have connected it do my Sql database, and my DB has NvarChar column that defines URL of an image that is located in Project folder.
I must put some controls to validate what i have entered.
I know how to validate Price and Name of a product, but how can i validate URL of an image that is located in Project folder?
Im using RegularExpressionValidator

URL example : **~/slike/goodybrush88254.jpg**

Answer (score 0):

May I know what kind of validation you want to do,

here we have two kinds of validations we can do,'
1. Validate the file exists in file system
2. Comparing the entered URL with the URL present in the database

Comment: Comparing the entered URL with the URL format, i need to add some new images so i need to enter URL

Comment: Can you try using the below regular expression for relative path URL validation.


^(?!www\.|(?:http|ftp)s?://|[A-Za-z]:\\|//).*